# Compute the limit of the sequence of functions, determine if $f(x)$ converges and show that $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly on R

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Compute $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)$, determine if f(x) is continuous and show that $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly on R for the sequence of functions $f_n(x) = \frac{x^2}{x^2+(1+nx)^2}$

attempt:

$\large \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^2}{x^2+(1+nx)^2} =  \frac{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x^2}{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(x^2+(1+nx)^2)} $

$\large =  \frac{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x^2}{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x^2+\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1+nx)^2}$

$\large = \frac{x^2}{x^2+ \infty} = \frac{x^2}{\infty} = 0$

$f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly if $\exists \epsilon>0: \forall N \exists n > N \exists x=-\frac{1}{n} \epsilon R \implies |f_n(x)-f(x)| = |f_n(-\frac{1}{n})-0|$
$\large = |\frac{\frac{1}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}+(1+n(\frac{-1}{n}))^2}-0|$
$\large =|\frac{\frac{1}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}-0| = |1-0| = 1  \geq \epsilon = 1$
So $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly on R.

Also, f(x) is not continuous because $f_n(x)$ does not converge to f(x) uniformly on R.

Comment: when you find the limit, you only get $\infty$ in the denominator if $x\not=0$. The case $x=0$ should be considered separately, but it is easily seen that the limit is $0$ again. So $f$ is the constant $0$ function, which is as continuous as it gets.

Comment: Be careful with the final sentence here: "Also, $f(x)$ is not continuous because $f_n(x)$ does not converge to $f(x)$ uniformly on $R$."  If the sequence *did* converge uniformly then $f$ would be continuous.  But there is no converse.  In fact take a good hard look at the limit function here and conclude (rather sheepishly) that indeed it is continuous.