# Uniform convergence in $[0,1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I have problems with exercise:

Study the uniform convergence on $[0, 1]$ of the sequence $f_n$ defined by:

$f_n = \displaystyle\frac{t^2}{t^2+(nt-1)^2}$

My attempt:

$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to{}\infty}{ \displaystyle\frac{t^2}{t^2+(nt-1)^2}} = 0, f(t) = 0 $ for all $t\in [0,1]$

How can I check that $\sup_{t \in [0,1]}|f_n(t)-f(t)| = 0$  ?

Thanks

Comment: Finding derivative?

Comment: [Searching with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f_n(t)%20%3D%20%5Cdisplaystyle%5Cfrac%7Bt%5E2%7D%7Bt%5E2%2B(nt-1)%5E2%7D%24&p=1) returns a few posts about the same sequence:  [Compute the limit of the sequence of functions, determine if $f(x)$ converges and show that $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly on R](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1538478), [Prove a sequence of functions is pointwise convergent but has no subsequence uniformly convergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1723367), or ,,,

Comment: ... [uniform convergence of $\frac{ x^2}{x^2+(1-nx)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2740840). See also: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your $f_n$ does not converge uniformly. Let $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$.

Then for every $n$, $$\left|f_n\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) - 0\right| = 1 > \varepsilon$$